# How would I specify data types in the map function?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I get data from a server which is an object containing four arrays of different object types. Now I try to map the data before subscribing to the observable such that I can use the correct classes in my frontend:

```
getData(){
    return this.http.get(this.authUrl + 'get/auf-data').pipe(
      map(({material, mat_auf, lokals, auf_analysen}) => {
        material.map(material => this.materialAdapter.adapt(material));
        mat_auf.map(auf => this.materialAufAdapter.adapt(auf));
        lokals.map(lokal => this.lokalAdapter.adapt(lokal));
        auf_analysen.map(analyse => this.aufAnalyseAdapter.adapt(analyse));
      })
    );
  }
```

The response is of type object containing four different arrays but somehow I get the error:

> Property 'material' does not exist on type 'Object' (repeated for: mat_auf, lokals and auf_analysen)

How would I specify the data types in the map function?

Comment: You need to provide more data. The question isn't clear at the moment without knowing the structure of the data coming from the server and to which form you're trying to convert to.

Comment: @MichaelD The adapters are working. The only problem is to specify the parameter of the map function. I am awaiting an object with four arrays. How would I specify that the parameters ```material```, ```mat_auf```, ```lokals```and ```auf_analysen``` are arrays such that I can map through them and change the objects in the arrays?

Comment: I mean, somewhere I have to specify what kind of data I am expecting to work with them when using RXJS map or not? If my assumption is true, where would I specify the response to map that response in the pipe function? For example how would I let the map-Operator know that I am expecting four arrays in an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to define the response time is as follows

```
  getData() {
    return this.http.get<{ material: any, mat_auf: any, lokals: any, auf_analysen: any; }>('get/auf-data').pipe(
      map(({ material, mat_auf, lokals, auf_analysen }) => {
        material.map(material => this.materialAdapter.adapt(material));
        mat_auf.map(auf => this.materialAufAdapter.adapt(auf));
        lokals.map(lokalisation => this.lokalAdapter.adapt(lokal));
        auf_analysen.map(analyse => this.aufAnalyseAdapter.adapt(analyse));
      })
    );
  }
```

If you look inside the type definitions of the `httpClient` you will see that one of the definitions for the get method is

```
 get<T>(url: string, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe: 'events';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
```

And ofcourse instead of `any` use whatever you need when you define your response body.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me few hours!